# .htaccess URL rewriting - https redirection / wildcard redirections / etc

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wildcard

I really struggle with .htaccess rules. 
I really don't understand how it works.. what is wrong with my code. I am testing multiple variations randomly without being able to understand where my issue is coming from.

I would like to have the following rules:

All http/www/non-www pointing to the same https://www URL:

- http://, https://, http:// www -> https://www.example.com
  (+keep all URL parameters e.g. Google UTM tracking)

Other https subdomains:

- blog.example.com (http or https) -> refers to: https://www.example.com/blog
- same for 'static' subdomain

URL rewriting for key pages of my domain:

- /overview (http or https, www or non-www) -> refers to https://www.example.com/page.php?id=overview)

My website allows users to create their page hosted under xxx.example.com

- http://xxx.example.com (not 'www' nor 'static' nor 'blog') -> keep as is (do not use 'https', as I don't have a wildcard SSL certificate)

There might be some conflicts with "subdomains" created through my Hosting service (BlueHost)

Subdomains  -  Root Domain  -  Document Root  -  Redirection

- (star)  -  .example.com  -  /public_html/event  -  not redirected
- blog  -  .example.com  -  /public_html/blog  -  not redirected -
- static  -  .example.com  -  /public_html/static  -  not redirected

I also have a CNAME configuration..:

- Host Record  -  Points to  -  TTL
- www    -  example.com  -  14400

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(static|blog)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/overview
RewriteRule ^ /page.php?id=overview [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/faq
RewriteRule ^ /page.php?id=faq [L]
(few more pages like that..)
```

There are multiple issues:

- http:// blog.example.com does not redirect to https version (but weirdly.. 'http:// static..' does redirect to https)
- http:// www.example.com/?param=123: '?param=123' is 'skipped'. I have tried adding 'QSA' flag... but does not work either.

(apologies, could not provide all http/https/www/non-www use cases - StackOverflow believes it is a spam)

I don't really know where to start to fix this...
1,000 thanks for your help!

Thanks
Damien.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Rewrite rule for http to https redirection and test.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Use  below rule to append '?param=123'.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Pandurang! 
This solves the 'http://blog.example.com' which now redirects to https version.

However, the parameters are still erased when access www.example.com/?param=123 ....